# Menu resizing on different languages

Tags: html, css

I have menu, that is on two different languages.My problem is that, on each of the languages, the names of the links in the menu, are different length because of the language differences , so what i'm trying to say is.. how can i set the menu to be resized and look like the same on each of the two languages.Because for example :

Lang 1:

```
Home | About us |
```

Lang 2:

```
Αρχική σελίδα | Εταιρεία |
```

You can see the differences in the length.

Comment: in the example you present, they are resized hence the difference, dont you mean fixed size for both?

Comment: yes fixed size, thnx for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose each item is wrapped in an anchor element like this:

```
<a href="#" class="class">Home</a>
```

Give the links or their container a certain class and then use that to set the items to a specified width.

```
a.class { width: 50px; border-right: 2px solid #000; display: block-inline; }
```

For display:block-inline; see comment.

A common way of building menus is wrapping each anchor element in a list item. Like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li>...</li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

And then targeting list items like this:

```
#menu li { width: 50px; float: left; }
.clear {clear: both;}
```

In this scenario you'll need to know how to work with floats (e.g. why do I need to have that div with clear on it at the end of the list?), but you won't have the problem with the not so well supported display type "inline-block"

Comment: Your idea is correct however <a> tags are inline elements therefore will not have the width unless you change that. See: http://tinkerbin.com/BkeGS5A5 inline-block i think is not supported in  IE6 that's why somepeople prefer to use floats as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think u want to space the letters u have to be more specific

```
<style>
 #text1 {letter-spacing:4px}

</style>

 <div id="text1"> Home | About us  </div>

 Αρχική σελίδα | Εταιρεία
```

here is an example of this result

http://jsfiddle.net/86DgH/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `width` property in CSS, using various units, but what would you set it to? Since you know that length requirements may vary, why force them to be equal? For example, you set the width to large enough for the longest item in Greek, it would look awkward in English:

```
 Home          | About us        |
```

If you really need to make the items equally wide (I suppose this is the heart of the question), setting `width` in `em` units is probably the least unreasonable setting. On the average, one character is about `0.5em` wide or somewhat less.